# How to I check the battery level on a Microsoft Surface from a WSL Ubuntu shell?

Tags: battery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

There are plenty of tutorials online for [checking your battery level in a ubuntu terminal](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-check-laptop-battery-status-in-terminal-in-linux/). The most common solution seems to be to use `upower`. However, when I run `upower` in a WSL Ubuntu shell in Windows 10 on my Surface Pro, I get this:

```
user@sp4-2637:~/the_thing$ sudo upower

(upower:665): UPower-WARNING **: Cannot connect to upowerd: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

Running with sudo priviliges yields the same result.

On my laptop running native ubuntu I can query the battery level like this;

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
```

However, this results in the following on my Surface:

```
user@sp4-2637:~$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
cat: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity: No such file or directory
```

How can I query the battery level in a WSL ubuntu shell for a Microsoft Surface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I wrote this question I found the solution so I thought I'd share it.

I don't know whether this is a peculiarity of the Surface hardware or of the WSL ubuntu version, but the directory structure appears to be different on this setup:

```
user@sp4-2637:~$ ls /sys/class/power_supply/
ac  battery  usb
```

Rather than looking in the `BAT0` directory I can find the battery level in `battery`:

```
user@sp4-2637:~$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity
100
```

Comment: I found `cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity` to work with WSL on Thinkpad T480 as well. It correctly displays the charges left on both batteries (internal + swappable).

Comment: how to change this? i had this problem too.. my correct path is /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity

Answer (score 1):

My Surface-Book-2 with WSL2 Ubuntu shell has the battery level in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity`

It may be different depending on hardware. Try the following locations

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity
```

Answer (score -1):

If tlp is a package available on WSL Ubuntu shell you can run the command

```
sudo tlp stat -b
```

Comment: WSL's kernel doesn't expose ACPI information which tlp requires in order to query the device's battery state,